# 2010 Subaru Legacy 2.5L CVT - Torque Specs for Intake Manifold

Tags: subaru, legacy, intake-manifold, torque-specification

Looking for the Torque Specs for the Intake Manifold.

Comment: Which engine is in your Legacy, the EJ253 or FB25?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 EJ253.

Comment: Turbo or naturally aspirated?  The intakes are different.

Comment: @ajayel Naturally aspirated. The turbo models don't have CVTs.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase the factory service manual (FSM) for your vehicle at https://techinfo.subaru.com/stis/#/login.

This has all of the component diagrams, wiring diagrams, specs, torque info, removal, installation, inspection and diagnostic steps.

There is a cost of US$35 for a 72 hour login which should be enough time to download all of the manuals that you might need.  Once you have downloaded the files required you don't have to pay again after that.

The FSM for my car is a 5,980 page PDF which I reference all of the time for DIY maintenance.